# How to Find a Perennial Seed Mix Resembling Piet Oudolf Gardens for Large-Scale Project?

Tags: seeds, perennials, oudolf

I'm planning to create a garden inspired by Piet Oudolf's iconic designs, particularly those seen in locations like Kensington Garden. However, I'm facing difficulty in sourcing a perennial seed mix that closely resembles the aesthetic of Oudolf's gardens for a large-scale project spanning 5000 m2.

I've conducted research on Oudolf's plant selection and design principles, noting the emphasis on naturalistic, wildflower-like arrangements with a mix of colors, textures, and heights. Now, I'm seeking guidance on how to find a seed mix that can help me achieve a similar look and feel for my garden.

[image]

[image]

Or should I purchase seeds of individual plants from Yelitto.com and plant each type seed in a dedicated zone?

Comment: I wonder how certain aspects of the design, like symmetry and proportion, could be  established without purposeful planting.  Looking at the distribution of eupatorium mac. Riesenschirm & scutellaria incana vs. iris sibiricia & deschampsia goldschleier for instance.

Comment: Are you definitely going with sowing seeds directly in the ground?

Comment: Yes, that is my plan. I am afraid that roots will take over if planting from seeds.